# SSO Login via SAML (Ping federator as my identity provider, Drupal as SP)

Tags: single-sign-on, ping, simplesamlphp

I am implementing SSO login via SAML (using Ping Federator as Idp, Drupal as Service Provider). In Idp initiated login, how does IDP knows to which service provider it should send SAML response?

Comment: Are you asking how you should provide that data to it, or how the software itself works?

Comment: In my organization we have four planets (QA, DEV, PROD, OPS), each planet has its own developer portal (Drupal). I just want to know how does IDP (Ping) knows to which SP it should send saml respone. (I want to clarify this before implementing SSO).

Answer (score 0):

That is implementation dependent but PingFederate would use a `partnerSpId` parameter to the IDP-init-SSO `/idp/startSSO.ping` endpoint documented at: https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf84/index.shtml#concept_idpEndpoints.html

Comment: Thanks @Hans Z. I understand that we add one or more links to idp/startsSSO.ping  end point to allow users to initiate sso to various SP's. My question is if we add more links to   /idp/startsSSO.ping, Does IDP send SAML response every SP or to the required SP?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question it sounds like you're asking about EntityId. Every connection (whether a IDP or SP) has an EntityId associated with it. The way any IDP tells which SP is connected to it is through the PartnerEntityId, setup through the connection inside PingFederate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @tater. My question is, in case of multiple SP's connected to single IDP, How does IDP knows to which SP it should send SAML response (IDP Initiated SSO) or IDP sends saml reponse each and every SP connected?

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: @Kaylan If you are connecting to multiple SPs with one IDP you are either using multiple connections or one connection using VSIDs on the IDP side. As mentioned before the way the IDP knows what "address" to send the SAML response to is by mapping the EntityId of the IDP to the EntityId of the SP. When the IDP initiates sso, it sends saml to the EntityId mapped as partnerspid.